# Sagepay iframe integration - Billing address

Tags: javascript, iframe, payment-gateway, opayo

I am considering using the iframe (low profile) Sagepay integration for my site. I have a few  questions regarding it:

1. Is it possible to NOT have the billing address fields show up in the iframe?
2. Is it possible to manipulate the transaction value on the payment page it self? SO for example, if the value was £100, and via a select dropdown box outside the iframe,I add another £2.00 to the value via javascript, how do I pass this value  to the iframe?

Comment: Is that allowed by their TOS? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I want to have the billing address on a step before the iframe page, so I want to prevent having the same billing address fields appearing again in the iframe form. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first point:-You can have the billing address page before iframe page.You have the option of customising the Low Profile pages, (including ‘NoAddress’ options) so that the look and feel of the payment pages is similar to your own site.

**For editing you need to download customtemplate and do the following things**

The default templates within this pack offer address fields which can be edited by the shopper while they are on the payment page. Should you wish to restrict this, you also have the option of setting the address to read-only or even show no address on the payment page at all.

Card_Details.xslt and Card_Details_Low.xslt files are provided for read-only and no address payment pages within the XSLT_AddReadOnly and XSLT_NoAddress directories respectively. The default XSLT directory contains the default files with address fields which can be modified by the shopper. If you wish to use address read-only templates or templates with no address simply copy the relevant files from the XSLT_AddReadOnly or XSLT_NoAddress directory and paste into the XSLT directory.

Note: Please ensure only one copy of the Card_Details.xslt and Card_Details_Low.xslt files are returned to the customer service team to ensure there is no confusion over which templates you wish to have uploaded.